# Elliptical border radius?

Tags: html, css

I would like to draw a plane with pure html and css.
My current basement is this:
http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/rq2ukwfk/

```
<div id="plane"></div>

#plane { 
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ccc; 
  border: solid 1px #000; 
  border-radius: 120px 0 0 120px; 
}
```

I would like to have the "cockpit" on the left side more elliptical, not round.
Is there a chance to realize this?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I dont think its possible with pure css. Check out SVG elliptical arcs:
http://www.svgbasics.com/arcs.html

Comment: http://codepen.io/dogagenc/pen/xbRKZx this is nice, but probably not helpful much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to get it more elliptical you could use:

```
border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rq2ukwfk/1/

You can do that in pure html and css but you will need more div elements. like something like this:

```
<div id="plane">
    <div id="cockpit-window"></div>
    <div id="left-wing"></div>
    <div id="right-wing"></div>
    <div id="tail"></div>
</div>
```

Some inspiration for you:

http://codepen.io/davidicus/pen/dDAqC

http://codepen.io/HugoGroutel/pen/dJniD

Comment: Very nice! Don't forget to mark the question as answered

Comment: Really simple ( actually obvious :D ) and nice workaround Christophe. Very well done.